# On Polar Sets with respect to Continuous Seminorms

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

In the following, $X$ is a Hausdorff locally convex topological vector space and $X'$ is the topological dual of $X$. If $p$ is a continuous seminorm on $X$ then we shall designate by $U_p$ the "$p$-unit ball", i.e,
$$U_p=\{x\in X: p(x)\le 1\}.$$

The polar set of $U_p$ is given by
$$U_p^o=\{f\in X':|f(x)|\le 1\quad \forall x\in U_p\}.$$

How do we prove that for each $x\in X$, we have
$$p(x)=\sup\{|f(x)|:f\in U_p^o\}.$$

I need some help...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $p(x)=0$. Then for all $\lambda>0$, $\lambda x\in U_p$ hence $|f(\lambda x)|\leqslant 1$ and $f(x)=0$ whenver $f\in U_p^0$.

If $p(x)\neq 0$, then considering $\frac 1{p(x)}x$, we get $\geqslant$ direction. For the other one, take $f(a\cdot x):=a\cdot p(x)$ for $a\in\Bbb R$; then $|f(v)|\leqslant p(v)$ for any $v\in\Bbb R\cdot x$. We extend $f$ by Hahn-Banach theorem to the whose space: then $|f(w)|\leqslant p(w)$ for any $w\in X$, giving what we want.

Comment: What I prove is that if $f\in U^0_p$, then $|f(x)|\leqslant p(x)$.

Comment: Maybe Im missing something. From the last sentce of your answer, how are we then to come up with $$p(x)\le\sup\{|f(x)|:f\in U_p^o\}?$$

Comment: I give an $f\in U_p^0$ such that $|f(x)|=p(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, but I still cannot get it. Im not that smart as you are.:)

Comment: The constructed $f$ is in $U_p^0$ because it's in the dual space, and if $p(u)\leqslant 1$, then $|f(u)|\leqslant p(u)\leqslant 1$.

Comment: I am almost there with the idea of your answer. Im still computing.:)

Comment: Umnn...I finally got it!! Thanks once again to you Sir.

Comment: You are welcome.